# ListView.SetOnItemClickListener doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, listener

I'm trying to create a ListView when a textView is clicked.  I need to add a listener to the items of this new ListView.

This is ListView:

[image]

My problem is that the method setOnItemClickListener() does not appear to work therefore I can't open the next ListView with the children of the item.

In the attached documents we can see 2 things:

- **Layout:** It shows a layout from android that of all the things he has, my 
  problem is in the ListView at the bottom.

  ```
  <include
      layout="@layout/app_bar_content_home"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/nav_view"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
      <LinearLayout

  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:paddingTop="84dp"
      android:paddingBottom="16dp"
      android:paddingLeft="16dp"
      android:paddingRight="16dp"
      android:background="@color/black">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="2dp"
          android:background="@color/white"/>

      <ListView
          android:visibility="gone"
          android:id="@+id/navigationList"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

      </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
  ```
- **Class:** This is only a fragment from the real class but it is enough. 
  What i'm trying to do here is when the user click the button that call the 
  method "buttonClicked" and his id is "title", I do several things but the 
  important one is call the ListView in the Layout file set his adapter and make 
  the class "setOnItemClickListener", which allows the items of the ListView to 
  be called:

  ```
  public void buttonClicked(View view) {
  NavigationView gg = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
  int id = view.getId();
  switch (id){
      case R.id.title:
          TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
          String titleText=title.getText().toString();
          LinearLayout needsGone=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.needsGone);
          ListView navigationListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.navigationList);
          if (titleText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.Content))){
              //TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
              title.setText(R.string.main_menu);
              needsGone.setVisibility(View.GONE);

              navigationListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              adapter = new NavigationAdapter(this, new ArrayList<NavigationClass>());

              navigationListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                      System.out.println("This is where it does not do anything);

                  }
              });
              navigationListView.setAdapter(adapter);

              new GetTaskDone().execute(request1Url);
          }else if(titleText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.main_menu))){
              title.setText(R.string.Content);
              needsGone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              navigationListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
          break;
  ...
  }
  }
  ```

The AsyncTask where i charge the information in the adapter:

```
        protected class GetTaskDone extends AsyncTask<String, Void, 
    List<NavigationClass>> {
            @Override
            protected List<NavigationClass> doInBackground(String... urls) {
                if (urls.length < 1 || urls[0] == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                List<NavigationClass> result = 
     appUtils.fetchDataApp_Navigation(urls[0]);
                return result;
                //navigationList=appUtils.fetchDataApp_Navigation(urls[0]);
                //return appUtils.fetchDataApp_Navigation(urls[0]);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<NavigationClass> data) {
                adapter.clear();

                if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
                    adapter.addAll(data);
                }
                //super.onPostExecute(result);
            }

        }
        }
```

Comment: A great example of question, rather than the fact that you're now in Stack Overflow... +1